# Filtering list of Objects on condition while counting on different condition

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of Objects that I would like to filter on condition (x && y) but I'd also want to count the occurences of a different condition while it's streaming, let's say (!x and z), I don't want to filter on this last condition I just want to count the occurences of it for whatever reason.

Is it possible to do it inside one stream without having to loop though my list twice?

Because at the moment I'd have to do something like this:

```
    List<MyClass> myClasses = ... //initialization of list of MyClass

    //filtering the objects that I need
    List<MyClass> filteredClasses = myClasses.stream().filter(MyClass::isX() && MyClass::isY()).Collectors.toList();

    //counting to store in a variable
    int isNotXandZCounter = myClasses.stream().filter(!MyClass::isX() && MyClass::isZ()).count();
```

Comment: It might be possible, but it'll be much simpler and probably just as efficient to just do two streams.  Your code as written is what I would write every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two streams or rewrite it as a loop.

However, if you really want to use a (and one) stream, here is what you could do (but **not recommended**, in my opinion **streams should not have side effects**).

```java
var count = new AtomicInteger(0);

var filteredClasses = myClasses.stream()
    .peek(clazz-> {
        if (!clazz.isX() && clazz.isZ()) {
            count.incrementAndGet();
        }
    })
    .filter(clazz -> class.isX() && clazz.isY())
    .toList();
```

But this would probably take longer to execute and has more compelexity than the solution you already have.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do it inside one stream without having to loop though my list twice?

Yes, use the for-cycle where you perform all the operations required at once. Then you will not need to loop through the list twice or more...

```java
myClasses.forEach(myClass -> {
    if (myClass.isX()) {
        if (myClass.isY()) {
            filteredClasses.add(myClass);   // x && y
        }
    } else {
        if (myClass.isZ()) {
            isNotXandZCounter++;            // !x && z
        }
    }
});
```

---

By the way, none of your lambda expressions are compilable.

Wrong:

- `MyClass::isX() && MyClass::isY()`
- `!MyClass::isX() && MyClass::isZ()`

Correct:

- `myClass -> myClass.isX() && myClass.isY()`
- `myClass -> !myClass.isX() && myClass.isZ()`

And collecting into a list is done via `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and not `.Collectors.toList()`.